# Sort order elasticsearch equal relevance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents:
`GET /books`

```
[{
    "title": "a book",
    "certified": true,
    "publisherId": 1
},
{   
    "title": "book a",
    "certified": false
    "publisherId": 2
}]
```

When I do a simple query string query on `title` I would like the results to be ordered on _score.
If the _score is equal, books that are **certified** should appear first.
If the _score is equal and books are certified, books that have **publisherId 1** should appear first.

How can I implement these types of tiebreaker rules/sorting rules in ES?

I would like to do something like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
{
    "query": {},
    "sort": [
        {"_score": {"order": "desc"},
        {"term": {"certified": true}},
        {"term": {"publisherId": "1"}}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `bool/should` queries to boost your documents according to your `certified` and `publisherId` constraints.

If you remove the `bool/should` in the following query, then all documents will be scored the same way. Adding the `bool/should` will boost the documents which are `certified` and those with `publisherId: 1`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "book",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "certified": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "publisherId": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. However, say book A matches on title for 0.5 and book B matches on title for 0.4 but is also certified and has publisherId 1. Is it then not possible for these boosts to result in a total score higher than 0.5?

Comment: You can decide to add a boost to the `match` clause so that the `should` ones are only "signals" that will give a little more boost to documents on case of a draw. Best is to try it out and tweak to your likings.